# why my macbook trackpad is not responding?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, touchpad

pointer in my macbook is moving randomly automatically and not responding to trackpad. what may be the real cause of this problem. is this a hardware problem or software or any other program is malfunctioning it?

Comment: i faced this problem 2-3 month ago and solved by antivirus program but now i faced it again

Comment: What model is it, & how old? Could be a swollen battery pressing on it.